# WSO2 ESB Call a REST API with text/plain content

Tags: rest, curl, wso2-esb

I need to call a REST API with plain text in body content.

A CURL command

`curl -X POST http://mydomain.test.corp/token -H "Content-Type: text/plain" -d "grant_type=password&username=testUName&password=123123"`

is giving my desired output. How can I build this as a proxy service. I was thinking of payload mediator but it only accepts media type xml/json.

I'm unable save `grant_type=password&username=testUName&password=123123` in the proxy service xml because of the ampersand sign I think.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use payload mediator and build a SOAP message that contains your plain text as a value for this node : `<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">`

Replace `&` with `&amp;` or use CDATA

Specify the message type (in order to use the appropriate messageFormatter) :

```
<property name="messageType" value="text/plain; charset=windows-1252" scope="axis2"/>
```

Just send this message

Complete sample :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="TestSOF" transports="http" startOnLoad="true" trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
            <format>
               <text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload"><![CDATA[grant_type=password&username=testUName&password=123123]]></text>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="messageType" value="text/plain" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8888/MockJSP.jsp"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment. When I use `<text xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/commons/ns/payload">`  the payload goes as it is (with the ampersand sign) `grant_type=password&amp;username=testUName&amp;password=123123`  which is resulting in an erroneous response.

Comment: You could try with a CDATA ?

Comment: Hi Jean, CDATA also converting the & into amp;

Comment: It works for me : I've updated my answer with a sample

Comment: sorry Jean, to me the amp; is getting logged, is there any synapse property enabling related to this?

Comment: Of course it is logged : if you use <log level="full"> inside the mediation, you log the soap message which is in xml format therefore, & is replaced by &amp;    If you want to see the real message sent by the esb...send it (if a file for exemple, using vfs) or use tcpmon to see post request details !